# Your UK visa application has been concluded

Tags: visas

i just received an email saying Your UK visa application has been concluded, does this mean that visa has been refused?

Comment: This question has been asked before, about several visa services and every time the answer was: "You can not tell from this email."

Comment: As two different emails are trending, one with word "issued" and in my case it is "concluded", almost all people are saying that email with word "concluded" means they are going to be refused. so i was very curious. :(